# Finding the Longest Word in a String

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, strings

Challenge:

> Return the length of the longest word in the provided sentence.

I've made a solution that works but it is kinda bad since the time complexity is \$O(n \log n)\$ and it involves mutation.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let strSplit = str.split(" ");
  let wordLengthArray = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++)
  {
    wordLengthArray.push(strSplit[i].length);
  }
  wordLengthArray.sort(function(a , b){return a - b});
  return wordLengthArray[wordLengthArray.length - 1];
}
```

I basically split the string, pushed all the word lengths in an empty array, then used the ascending sort function. After that I returned the last index of the new array which is the longest length.

Test Cases:

```
findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog") should return 6.
findLongestWordLength("May the force be with you") should return 5.
findLongestWordLength("Google do a barrel roll") should return 6.
findLongestWordLength("What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow") should return 8.
findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology") should return 19.
```

I would appreciate some hints/tips on a better algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating an array of strings (using `str.split(" ")`) as well as an array of numbers (`wordLengthArray`), then sorting `wordLengthArray`.  All three of those operations are wasteful, if you are aiming for performance.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let maxLen = -1;
  for (var i = 0, j; (j = str.indexOf(" ", i)) != -1; i = j + 1) {
    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, j - i);
  }
  return Math.max(maxLen, str.length - i);
}

console.log(6 == findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
console.log(5 == findLongestWordLength("May the force be with you"));
console.log(6 == findLongestWordLength("Google do a barrel roll"));
console.log(8 == findLongestWordLength("What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow"));
console.log(19 == findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology"));
```

Depending on the browser/interpreter, your function is [33% to 86% slower](https://jsperf.com/findlongestwordlength/1) than mine.

Answer (score 3):

What I'm seeing is that you touch the data twice. This isn't necessary for retrieving a simple fact about the data.

Consider, saving the length of each word and comparing lengths as you go along. Even with a perfectly linear sort function (That is, O(n-1)) this will still cut down on algorithm complexity, simply because you aren't calling a sort function at all.

EDIT: I had a variable saving the word as well as the length, but after reading over your question again, I found that that isn't what you were looking for.
EDIT2: I removed my code because you said you wanted HINTs. sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Kruga, here is a javascript implementation of my original pseudo code which gives the answer in a single pass. No splits, no arrays, no sorting:

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
    let currentCount = 0;
    let currentMax = 0;
    for(let char of str) {
        if(char != " ") {
            currentCount += 1;
        }
        else {
            if(currentCount > currentMax) currentMax = currentCount;
            currentCount = 0;
        }
    }
    if(currentCount > currentMax) currentMax = currentCount; // take care of last word
    return currentMax;
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7s3d5Lgt/) is the code written in javascript

Answer (score 2):

This is like getting biggest number algorithm.

```js
const text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';

const longWord = n => {
  let arr = n.split(' ');

  let longestWordCount = arr[0];

  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (element.length > longestWordCount.length) {
      longestWordCount = element;
    }
  });
  console.log(longestWordCount.length);
}

longWord(text);
```